# First time with closures, I can't tell whats wrong?

Tags: javascript

New to closures, i hope i can make this make at least some sense...
I need two functions, being called with two different click events, to share the same flag variable, but use it separately..
the flag is supposed to prevent the ajax call from being called more than once.

i'll provide the code that worked before i added the closure
and sum it up incase you dont want to read throught it.

ignore:

```
showColdMenu.pause(0)
showHotMenu.restart()
```

it's some code from the gsap library, just animating.

---

- the global variable hotFetched=false  ( will bet set to true once the code is ran in the event listener)
- the code in the event listener fetches data, enters a loop creates HTML markup for the data and puts it on the page.

-an if statement runs only if hotFetched is false

-hotFetched is set to true, then the block of code ends.

(hotFetched set to true to ensure when the button is clicked  more than once it doesn't make the call and keep displaying the same data over and over again on the page.)

---

```
let hotFetched=false;

  hotButton.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    showColdMenu.pause(0)
    showHotMenu.restart()


if(!hotFetched){
  fetch('./menu.JSON', {
  headers : { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
   }
})
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data => {
    drinks = [...data.hotDrinks];

    for (var i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++) {
        hotMenu.innerHTML += `<div class="menuImgContainer"><img src="${drinks[i].img}" alt="${drinks[i].drink}" class="menuImg"><span class="name">${drinks[i].drink}
        </span></div>`
    }

 })
}
 hotFetched=true;
});
```

---

The problem is i needed two of these exact same big blocks of code, one for hot and one for cold, so i created a function they could share.

(with an attempted closure)

---

```
function fetchMenu(menu,temp){    
 let fetched=false;

return function(){

    if(!fetched){
        fetch('./menu.JSON', {
            headers : { 
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json'
             }
          })
          .then(response=>response.json())
          .then(data => {
          drinks = [...data[temp]];

      for (var i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++) {
        menu.innerHTML += `<div class="menuImgContainer"><img src="${drinks[i].img}" alt="${drinks[i].drink}" class="menuImg"><span class="name">${drinks[i].drink}
        </span></div>`
    }

  }
}
```

---

and called it like this:

```
hotButton.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    showColdMenu.pause(0);
    showHotMenu.restart();

    let fetchHotMenu= fetchMenu(hotMenu, "hotDrinks");
    fetchHotMenu();

});
```

---

the flag stays true, and html keeps getting dynamically created and put onto the page.

Comment: you need to set `fetched` to true in your fetch callback

Answer (score 0):

The way the code is written now, every time you click, a new identical function instance (along with a new closure) is created and invoked. What you want is for the same function instance to be used each time. So just move the creation of it outside your click event.

```
let fetchHotMenu= fetchMenu(hotMenu, "hotDrinks");

hotButton.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    showColdMenu.pause(0);
    showHotMenu.restart();

    fetchHotMenu();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time kind sir